# Render blazor components dynamically from a factory

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have an `IList<IControl>` that is an interface that derives from `IComponent`, every implementation of the interface inherits from `ComponentBase`. The component is instantiated from a factory dynamically (it returns a component compatible with input's type).

Now I want to render this list, but I do not know how, this is my ControlsContainer.razor:

```
@foreach (var control in OrderedControls)
{
    <div @key=@Guid.NewGuid().ToString()>

        @RenderWidget(control)

    </div>
}
```

I want to avoid a switch/if-else if with every component type (they are loaded dynamically with reflection, I do not need to register them somewhere).

Comment: So if I've read this right, you have a concrete list `IList<IControl>` of instances of concrete components you've created in a factory - say input controls for a form.  What you want to do is add them to a page with a "factory" control?  Yes/No?  I'm trying to understand the problem before suggesting for a solution.

Comment: side note but that `@key=...` part is very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but the following should work, or at least put you on the right path ...

```
@foreach (var control in OrderedControls)
{
    <div @key=@Guid.NewGuid().ToString()>

        @RenderWidget(control)

    </div>
}

@code {
    RenderFragment RenderWidget(IControl control)
    {
        var concreteType = control.GetType();
        RenderFragment frag = new RenderFragment(b =>
        {
            b.OpenComponent(1, concreteType);
            b.CloseComponent();
        });
        return frag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but this creates a new instance of the `IControl` concrete type. I have created a temporary method that with reflection calls a private type and gets the RenderFragment of the component. I do not like this solution but I think it is one of the limits of blazor.

Comment: Ah, I understand.  So, you're wanting to keep concrete references of Razor Components and use them on demand?  I'm curious as to what your use case is for this.  I presume that a previous action on the component has established some state that you want to maintain 'within the component' but re-use the component in different places?